# Proper use of Heading (<h1>,<h2>...) tags for SEO on Product Page

Tags: seo, meta-tags

I've done a lot of searching and can't seem to find a straight answer and conflicting information. Since this applies to all who have a Magento eCommerce site, I thought I would post the question here.

Here is what I am *assuming* is correct:

`H1` Product Name

`H2` Product Short Description / Product name above the description (I've seen this done on large eCommerce sites and do not know if this is proper)

`H3` Product Long Description / Product Specifications / Reviews

`H4` Product Price

EDIT: Not sure if MPN (Manufacturer Part Number)  would fit into this?

**Question 1: What is the proper usage of `H` tags on the product view page?**

And as a second portion to my question, (again based on large eCommerse sites) I have mashed together the product name with the product short description as an `H1` tag (the short description is not present on my site).

**EXAMPLE:**

> Product name:  *Canon LS-100TS* Product  Short Description: *5936A002AA - LS-100TS, LCD 10 digits*

Final output name in front end (`H1`):

> *Canon LS-100TS 5936A002AA - LS-100TS, LCD 10 digits*

**Question 2: Can this be negatively viewed by search engines or is it acceptable?**

Comment: Make sure that the Magento theme you are using, uses a **h2** tag or just a div tag wrapped around your logo in the header, instead of a **h1** tag. Because it will hurt your SEO and ranking if you have two **h1** tags on the page. The only **h1** tag should be around your product name title (product pages), category name title (category pages), other named title (static pages).

Comment: Great information, I'm surprised that this hasn't gotten more attention. Hopefully more can chime in to benefit everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer: I'm not an SEO expert**

I have worked with a number of companies who have many analysts on staff who worry about this every day. In my experience the rules around use of H tags is always shifting. Here are the current "rules" (according to Google) as I understand them:

- **You determine the priority of your own content**. There is no hard-and-fast rule around which piece of content is the most important to you.
- **Visual styling is important**. Apparently you can lose ranking or be demoted for using high-ranking H-tags (`h1`, `h2`) but making them small in font or a low-contrast color.
- **They only do so much**. They're not the be-all-end-all of your ranking content. They're one small factor. Make the choice that best represents your product, not to game SEO.
- H4's and beyond do little to help Google make sense of your content. Use more semantic containers (`header`, `article`, `section`) to help organize content.
- Other things factor into SEO like multimedia, meta tags, etc. Optimizing those in tandem with well-written heading tags will go a long way.

In short: above all content matters. Make sure content is original and readable by Google. Make decisions that help your *customers* first, and Google second.

Comment: great information and consistent with what I've been reading. Do you know if my understanding of each H value correct? I am particularly interested in the H tag for description, price and if the MPN could/should or shouldn't be included in a H tag.